# Auto down to next row if mod 3 = 0

Tags: excel, vba

I try to write code to insert value in a range have 3 column and row based on array of values. I need to insert value from 1 to 1000 to my range as 1,2,3 next row, 4,5,6 next row, 7,8,9 next row until 1000.
Please someone help me, I have tried to find in stackoverflow but no result match

Comment: I think you mean col1 of row1 is 1 and col2 of row1 is 2 and col3 of row1 is 3 and col1 of row2 is 4 and ..., Am I right ?

Comment: I change my declarations to remove error ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test2()
    Dim i As Integer, r As Integer
    r = 1
    For i = 1 To 1000
        If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
            Cells(r, 3) = i: r = r + 1
        Else
           Cells(r, i Mod 3) = i
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: unfortunately my English is not good, so reluctant to show an example without explanation

Comment: @Vitallic that's why Stack Overflow's posts can be edited :) include your explanation in what you can figure out in english, and someone will come in and edit it into better shape (just like victor already did :) )

Answer (score 0):

If you are about Excel;
If first row is 1 :
`Col1 = (ROW() - 1) * 3 + 1`,
`Col2 = (Row() - 1) * 3 + 2`,
`Col3 = (ROW() - 1) * 3 + 3`

Else : @fr = row number of first row :
`Col1 = (ROW() - @fr) * 3 + 1`,
`Col2 = (ROW() - @fr) * 3 + 2`,
`Col3 = (ROW() - @fr) * 3 + 3`

A Better Way is use This : (@fr = 1 if first row is 1)
`=(ROW() - @fr) * 3 + COLUMN()`

In VBA add this:

```
Public Function myFunc(row as integer, col as integer, Optional fr As Integer = 1) As Integer
    myFunc = (row - fr) * 3 + Col + 1
End Function
```

Then use it. 
For you:

```
Sub test2() 
    Dim i As Integer, row As Integer, col As Integer 
    a = 1 
    For i = 1 To 1000 
        row = (i - 1) \ 3 + 1
        col = (i - 1) mod 3 + 1
        Cells(row, col) = myfunc(row, col)
    Next i 
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried to write this because I don't know how to use your code, and this is my code please help me use your code or comment my code because my code have double value "1" in the first row. <code> 
Sub test2()
Dim i, a, t As Integer

a = 1
For i = 1 To 100
t = i Mod 3 + 1
    If i Mod 3 = 0 Then 'next row
    a = a + 1
    Cells(a, t) = i
    Else 'keep row
    Cells(a, t) = i
End If
Next i
End Sub
<code/>

Comment: It not work, argument type mismatch. cause of row is integer value

Comment: Pardon me, I forgot to change Declarations.